# How do I convert many text files from <some_encoding> to utf8-no-bom?

Tags: windows, conversion, encoding, character-encoding, textfiles

I'm looking to convert lots of text files (40+) from ISO-Latin-1 to UTF8-no-bom. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I wrote what encoding is above. ISO-Latin

Comment: I could have sworn your original revision did not indicate the encoding hence the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527269/any-tool-to-convert-bulk-php-files-to-utf-8-without-bom):

- ```
  You can get a tool such as iconv from GnuWin32 and 
  run a batch script to process all of your files that way.

  But what encoding are they now? If they're ANSI, 
  and you're not using any bytes with values => 128,
  then they're already BOM-less UTF-8.
  Perhaps you can use that to narrow down the number of 
  files you'd have to process - maybe enough that you only have a
  few files to convert (and might prefer to do it on an individual basis).
  ```
- ```
  Actually, I do it with Notepad++.
  Before trying this, you must make a backup of your files.
  You need to create a macro that does this:


  Convert the currently opened file to UTF-8 w/o BOM;
  Select all the text in your file, and copy it
  (why this? it looks like a bug. if you won't do this,
  your file will be replaced with your current clipboard content...);
  Save the current file;
  Close the current file.
  Save this macro.

  Now, open your PHP files, and run it with the "Run a Macro Multiple 
  Times..." command. If you opened 100 files, let it run for 100 times.
  ```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$url = getenv("SERVER_ADDR");
//$url = getenv(HTTP_POST_VARS);
$rootdir='d:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ecoder';
$dir="."; 
$files=scan_dir($rootdir);
  foreach ($files as $file) {
    $info = pathinfo($file);
    $extF =$info["extension"];
    if ($extF == "php" || $extF == "txt" || $extF == "js" || $extF == "css") { 
     echo $file ."
";
     $data = file_get_contents($file);
     writeUTF8File($file, $data);
     echo $file.' was converted to UTF8
';
    }
  }


//use this function to get all files inside a directory (including subdirectories)

function scan_dir($dir) {
    $arrfiles = array();
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
            chdir($dir);
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                    if (is_dir($file)) {
                        $arr = scan_Dir($file);
                        foreach ($arr as $value) {
                            $arrfiles[] = $dir."/".$value;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $arrfiles[] = $dir."/".$file;
                    }
                }
            }
            chdir("../");
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    return $arrfiles;
}

function writeUTF8File($filename,$content) { //บันทึกไฟล์เป็น UTF8
        $f=fopen($filename,"w"); 
        # Now UTF-8 - Add byte order mark 
        fwrite($f, pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf)); 
        fwrite($f,$content); 
        fclose($f); 
} 

?>
```

Comment: In the future, please edit your answers to correct any mistakes instead of posting new ones.

Comment: It would be really useful to explain how to run the code.